# Systemd openvpn up script not working

Tags: linux, openvpn

my openvpn client.conf includes an option "--up /home/averagejoey2000/bin/port_forward.sh"
but whenever I run `systemctl openvpn-client@client.service`, the process fails because openvpn attached arguments to the script, when the script accepts no arguments.

```
 openvpn-client@CA_Toronto.service - OpenVPN tunnel for CA_Toronto
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-14 09:16:02 PST; 4s ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 28780 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --suppress-timestamps --up /home/averagejoey2000/bin/port_forwarding.sh --nobind --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 28780 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: /usr/bin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.11.10.6 peer 10.11.10.5
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: /home/averagejoey2000/bin/port_forwarding.sh tun0 1500 1558 10.11.10.6 10.11.10.5 init
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: Unrecognized option: tun0
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: Usage: /home/averagejoey2000/bin/port_forwarding.sh
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program exited with error status: 1
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 openvpn[28780]: Exiting due to fatal error
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 systemd[1]: openvpn-client@CA_Toronto.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN tunnel for CA_Toronto.
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 systemd[1]: openvpn-client@CA_Toronto.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 14 09:16:02 Mjolnir4 systemd[1]: openvpn-client@CA_Toronto.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`
```

I don't know what to append such that `tun0 1500 1558 10.11.10.6 10.11.10.5 init` is not passed as an argument to `~/bin/port_forwarding.sh`

EDIT1
port_forwarding.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Enable port forwarding when using Private Internet Access
#
# Usage:
#  ./port_forwarding.sh

error( )
{
  echo "$@" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

error_and_usage( )
{
  echo "$@" 1>&2
  usage_and_exit 1
}

usage( )
{
  echo "Usage: `dirname $0`/$PROGRAM"
}

usage_and_exit( )
{
  usage
  exit $1
}

version( )
{
  echo "$PROGRAM version $VERSION"
}


port_forward_assignment( )
{
  echo 'Loading port forward assignment information...'
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]; then
    client_id=`head -n 100 /dev/urandom | sha256sum | tr -d " -"`
  fi
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then
    client_id=`head -n 100 /dev/urandom | shasum -a 256 | tr -d " -"`
  fi

  json=`curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null`
  if [ "$json" == "" ]; then
    json='Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding'
  fi

  echo $json
}

EXITCODE=0
PROGRAM=`basename $0`
VERSION=2.1

while test $# -gt 0
do
  case $1 in
  --usage | --help | -h )
    usage_and_exit 0
    ;;
  --version | -v )
    version
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    error_and_usage "Unrecognized option: $1"
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

port_forward_assignment

exit 0
```

from https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/23431/new-pia-port-forwarding-api

EDIT2
Comments
Max-P Max-P
Posted on February 1  Posts: 90 
Additional note: the port must be requested within 2 minutes of connecting to the VPN. Past this point the API is no longer available and will just refuse connection.
Quote
OpenVPN OpenVPN
Posted on February 1  Posts: 81 
How is this new API better than the old one? What's the difference? Please explain.
Quote
Max-P Max-P
Posted on February 1  Posts: 90 
@OpenVPN: A lot easier to use and safer, mostly. The previous API required to call the website, which had to be done on the VPN so that the API could see which server you're on. You also had to pass it your local address too which usually involved parsing `ifconfig` or `ip addr`, and you had to call it once every hour to keep your port. Overall it required a bit of effort. Now you can just slap it as your `--up`script on stock OpenVPN and be done with it :)
Quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think this script should be run when OpenVPN starts up? The Web page you refer to **never** mentions it; also, up/down script in OpenVPN are used to perform custom configuration of routing (for instance, if the new routes belong to a different routing table than the default one), which is why they are passed the bevvy of variables that you see in your logs.

Besides, your script does not need any variable to be passed to it, which is why you may safely transform the two lines

```
error_and_usage "Unrecognized option: $1"
    ;;
```

into

```
    ;;
```

and your script should work. Just keep in mind that your output (*echo $json*) will go to the system log; if you wish to find it elsewhere, be sure to modify the *echo $json* line as

```
echo $json >> /path/to/some/convenient/file
```

Comment: The api only accepts port requests within 2 minutes of VPN up. A commenter recommends putting it in --up, because if you forget, you need to disconnect and reattach